# Не работает watch в gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, watch

Не работает watch в gulp. А именно не работает следующий код.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch('./app/*.html', gulp.parallel(browserSync.reload ));
});
```

По идее watch должен следить за всеми файлами html
При запуске локального сервера, когда изменяется файл html, не перезагружается браузер.
Если заменить *.html на index.html, то watch следит за index.html и перезагружает браузер.
Подскажите, где ошибка? Как сделать так, чтобы watch следил за всеми файлами?

Answer (score 1):

Замените `'./app/*.html'` на `'./app/**/*.html'`. Тогда следить будет за всеми html-файлами, независимо от их уровня вложенности.